# Best way to set height dynamically for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that holds cells that can show video, html, and images, and a UI of audio playback. That's effectively 3 different cells that could potentially be in the tableView in any given point in time. Cells of the same type can have different heights. That's the problem I'm trying to solve. Out of all the tutorials I've watched/read through, none taught me how to set the calculate then set the heights dynamically. I've only read stuff that show you how to tableViews with different cells that have static heights. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apply auto-layout in table view cell for cell-items and bound it with both top and bottom and use `estimatedHeightForRowAt` as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Or you can manually set the height for different rows as:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50 // rather than 50 return height you need to set
}
```